# access to client -machine directories while logged-in as ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-server

im logged into server by ssh from macOs terminal `username_on_server@server_linux:/$` but i couldnt come inside the mac client (while im logging as server user), to change directory or smthing inside client machine to send to server machine
e.g. I need to copy some file or directory from client to server as ssh but any changing directory refers to server

```
my-mac:~ newuser$ ssh 'username_on_server@server_linux'

username_on_server@server_linux:/home$ pwd
/home
```

Comment: ... Open 2 Terminals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are logged into server_linux you cannot change/modify the client machine, basically the SSH connection is like if you were in the remote server. If you want to copy a file from client to server use instead `scp`

```sh
scp client_file username_on_server@server_linux:/server_path
```